# why is my control name been rendered as text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Im new to mvc so this I am sure is a stupid question.
I have created a view that looks something simlar to

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.RoundedCorner()
 {
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
 }
}
```

Rounded corner is a just a helper class to create a nice looking rounded corner css box. When the page is rendered the form is created and also the rounded css box is applied however so does the text

> MyProductName.Helpers.RoundedCorner

I assume this is because im doing something wrong but what? any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown how does your `RoundedCorner` helper look like but because I have some souvenirs of having [written something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084764/create-a-html-helper-for-mvc/5084909#5084909) you seem to be missing a `using` statement:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    using (Html.RoundedCorner())
    {
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    }
}
```